# android:fragments crash on screen Orientation

Tags: android

I've made two XML files one for portrait mode and the other is for landscape

When i start the app it runs normally and after flipping the screen for the second time it crashes and gives this error:`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet`.

Eventhough the landscape xml file contains static fragments and the portriat one contains nothing(in order to add the fragments dinamically on further steps).Here is my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:name="com.example.alihaidar.fragmentlab.fragList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frag_list"
    />
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.alihaidar.fragmentlab.fragContent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frag_content"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

and this is mainActivity it contains nothing :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Comment: Add your crash log here

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.alihaidar.fragmentlab, PID: 8299
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet.

Comment: and your fragment code

Comment: Give us more detailed logcat error sack, maybe line where this error happens. Also Fragment code

Comment: Try to put this in the `Manifest` for your `Activity`: `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

Comment: MainActivity it contains nothing but fragList and fragContent have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a validation to check if the Fragment is attached to its parent  using [isAdded()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) method:

```
if (!isAdded()){
    return;  //Not attached
}else{
   //Attached!
}
```

> [isAdded()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) Return true if the fragment is currently added to its
>   activity.

---

Another option, define in your activity the property:

```
<activity 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

to avoid the destruction of the parent activity when you rotate the device.